# Can you make croissants with compound butter?

Tags: baking, pastry, puff-pastry

Has anyone ever tried making croissants (or leavened puff pastry) with compound butter (e.g. basil butter, cinnamon butter)? Are there any practical issues with this? Will particles in the butter break the layers of dough? Will sugary butters burn before the dough is fully cooked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made garlic-butter laminated savoury rolls, using roughly the same method as for croissants. It works reasonably well, but I have found that I need to grind the garlic pretty finely. If there are lumps they end up tearing the dough during the lamination. Another issue is that it's even more important to keep everything cold. I work on a chilled marble slab, and that works pretty well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you think the added moisture from the garlic negatively impacts anything? I'd heard that you should use unsalted butter in making pastry dough since the lower moisture results in a better product, so I wonder.

Comment: I don't think that the little moisture has much impact. On the other hand, garlic is supposed to impede the yeast [cite](http://www.thefreshloaf.com/node/2590/garlic-and-its-effect-yeast). I have only made it twice, and in both cases it rose properly, though.